# Change data type in text file from string to float Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read in a 4 column txt file and create a 5th column. Column 1 is a string and columns 2-4 are numbers, however they are being read as strings. I have two questions - my python script is currently unable to perform multiplication on two of the columns because it is reading columns 2-4 as strings. I want to know how to change columns 2-4 (which are numbers) to floating numbers and then create a 5th column that is two of the previous columns multiplied together.

Comment: Please post your code and clearly explain what parts you find are not working. The more you can provide and explain, the better we can help. This is a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse String to Float or Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast strings to floats in python like so.

```
>>> float('1.25')
1.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast them to float using `float(x)` method where x is the string that contains the float

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you iterate over the Lines, you could run the string through a try-except operation like:

```
try:
    float(value)
except ValueError:
    pass
    #Or do some kind of error handling here
```